# Launching specific remote kernels in parallel

Tags: numerical-integration, parallelization, remote-access, high-performance-clusters

For some reason I found that my numerical integration runs much faster on *Mathematica* 9 than on *Mathematica* 10.

Since I sent my calculation to a cluster with 24 cores with the following command

```
Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"];
LaunchKernels[RemoteMachine["machine_name", 24]];
```

and the calculation is running in *Mathematica* 10. Therefore, I would like to know if there is any way to tell the machine that I want to use *Mathematica* 9 instead of 10?

The script is running with command like math-9 -script.